# Unity - How to land in the exact position i want?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics-engine

Im busy trying to get my ball to land in the exact position it should after every bounce which is the centre of the next cylinder every time it bounces from one to the other.

At the minute i am using rigidbody add force in fixed update. The idea is that the ball will always move to the right and bounce on every impact it has. The problem i am having at the minute is the trajectory - I want the ball to always land at the exact centre of the next cylinder!

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You haven't given sufficient information; where is the ball starting from - some point at a distance, and you set the initial speed, direction and elevation? Is there air resistance in the physics engine?

Comment: Thats a fair point, i wrote this in a hurry. Ill edit now

Comment: I'm afraid your description is very confusing - do you want the ball to bounce from one cylinder to another, or just have it land on a certain cylinder when launched from a point elsewhere

Comment: Updated the question, i hope im explaining now haha.

Comment: So you want to apply a vertical impulse to the ball when it lands on a cylinder? That can be done, but we need more information - 1) the coefficient of restitution between the ball and the cylinder, 2) presence of air resistance, 3) how you are proposing to *initiate* the motion (the cylinders cannot add any *horizontal* speed to your ball, so it has to start with the correct speed)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not related to programming.